# Javascript Redirection not working

Tags: redirect

I am trying to redirect to external url. I use the below code.

```
<script>
window.location.href= "www.radar.com";
</script>
```

But it redirect the url to this `http://localhost/webtask/www.radar.com`. But I want to 
redirect to **www.radar.com**. I am unable to find the issue.Please help....

Comment: prefix location with protocol (http:// or https://)

Comment: Now i have added http://www.radar.com. it is working fine.

Comment: Actually this url is added from admin panel. Suppose if the user did not add the http: . In this case how will i manage it.

Comment: So the redirect page is automatically generated by the hosting service?

Answer (score 1):

You needed to put the whole URL like below.

```
window.location = "http://www.radar.com";
```